# CSS style same type of element differently

Tags: css

Lets say I have CSS like this:

```
div.form label input {
      /* some css here */
}
```

However this will apply to all of my `input` elements. I want to have another CSS that applies to an input type, so how do I do this? Creating a class won't work here because it will just be ignored because of this first one.

**Use case:**

I have 5 text input that I want to style *x* way and I have 3 text input that I want to style *y* way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [attribute selector](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), supported by IE7+, and every other modern browser..

If you want, say, text inputs, use this:

```
input[type="text"] {
    color: red; /* Or whatever */
}
```

Inputs of type `password` would be like this, for example:

```
input[type="password"] {
    color: blue; /* Or whatever */
}
```

And so on. It's not used that often, but should be, to use other attributes and even *custom ones*. [This quirksmode page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attribute.html) gives good examples.

---

Here is one of my own:

```
<div foo="bar"></div>

/* Any `div` element with `foo` having any value */
div[foo]
{
    background: red;
}

/* Any `div` element with `foo` having a specific value (bar) */
div[foo="bar"]
{
    background: green;
}
```

If we're applying this to `text` inputs, you can use their `name` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" name="email">

input[name="username"]
{
    background: blue;
}

input[name="email"]
{
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: both are for type text, I want the some of the type text to have different styling...

Answer (score 1):

to style input controls try this:

```
input[type='text'], input[type='password'], input[type='radio'], input[type='checkbox'],input[type='submit'], textarea, select {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

You can then style different input controls differently.

EDIT:

```
.red
{
color:red;
}

.blue
{
color:blue;
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id=2txt1" class="red"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id=2txt1" class="blue"/>
```

Comment: ok - then can you specify the class names for each text box? (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an attribute selector:

```
input[type="text"]
{
    color: #f00;
}
```

This will select all inputs with type of text, regardless of id or class.  IE7 and IE8 support attribute selectors only if a !DOCTYPE is specified and is not supported in IE6 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

One of my first questions would be are you wrapping your inputs in a label for your markup?  I guess that's more of a preference thing. I would usually have those separate, like:

```
<label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
```

secondly, and again more of a personal preference, I would give my form an id:

```
<form id="contactform">
```

So, with that off my chest, I agree with the above answers, but may do a bit of both depending on the design. I would set some global styles using the attribute selector as mentioned above, then style the inputs on the page if I needed to with the id if I needed to, or use a wrapper div with a class.

All good options. I guess I hope the css in the question is really just some arbitrary example, cause to me the css doesn't make much sense.